# For loop with a text variable in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a for loop in R. But I am stuck at substituting for my running variable inside a text argument. Here is what I want to do:

```
x <- 0
for (j in 1:9) {
x[j] = length(vehicles[vehicles$trans == "Automatic S(j)" ,][, 58])
}
```

x should be a vector of the length of the variable vehicle$trans when it takes the values "Automatic S(1)", "Automatic S(2)", ..., "Automatic S(9)". How may I fix this for loop?

Comment: possibly `vehicle$trans == paste0("Automatic (S[", j, "])" , ][, 58])`. I haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- 0
for (j in 1:9) {
    x[j] = length(vehicles[vehicles$trans == paste("Automatic S(", j, ")", sep="") ,][, 58])
}
```

Comment: What is `S[]`?  Is that a variable or just part of a string name?

Comment: The string part should take the values: "Automatic S(2)", ..., "Automatic S(9)". So, both S and () are part of the string name.